# How do I use String.format to display value with leading space?

Tags: java

I am trying to counting a number from 1 in an ascending order and I need to add leading space to each line, the trick is that there is no space for the first line, 1 space for the second number, 2 spaces for the third line and n spaces for the (n + 1)th number.

**For example if user inputs value 4 , The expected output in the consle should be** : [image]

I have done some research, I couldn't figure it out. I think it's related to String.format method. Any ideas? Your effort will be greatly appreciated!

```
        int c = 0 ;
        int num = input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        while (c < num)
        {
            c++;
       System.out.println(String.format("%"+3+"s",c)); //this code gives the same length of leading space on everyline which is not what i want.

        }
```

Comment: Well, you have ask a static number of spaces `%3s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
      int c = 0 ;
    int num = input.nextInt();
    input.close();
    while (c < num)
    {
        c++;
   System.out.println(String.format("%"+c+"s",c)); 
    }
}
```

instead of 3 use c

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple loop to show you how this works :

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; ++i){
    System.out.format("%"+i+"s\n", String.valueOf((char)(i+'a'-1)));
}
```

Basicly, this will create the format %#s where you update the # to the number you want.

I used `System.out.format` but you can use `String.format` as well

**/!\ The minimum value to this flag is 1**

Output

```
a
 b
  c
   d
    e
     f
      g
       h
        i
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to add a space to a StringBuilder for every new number.

```
StringBuilder spaces = new StringBuilder();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int userChoice = 0;
while(userChoice != -1){
    userChoice = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print(spaces.toString());
    System.out.print(userChoice);
    System.out.println();
    spaces.append(" ");
}
```